# how does nhibernate and asp.net work together?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

does anyone know a good code sample for asp.net 3.5 and nHibernate? I am looking to have a few samples about one to many relation ships and mapping in nHIbernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many good examples on the internet, here is a good one with a step by step guide :
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Your-very-first-NHibernate-application-Part-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best article around is this one:

```
 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx
```

It's not the easiest, but it's the most comprehensive. I found it very useful.

This article, it's more basic and can cover what you looking for.

```
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Nhibernate_Made_Simple.aspx
```

Please note that both are based on old versions of NHibernate and do mapping in xml. With latest versions of NHibernate the Fluent mapping has been introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of Benjamin Perkins' book "Working with NHibernate 3.0" (it's actually about nh 3.2) and/or download the sample code. It's a really good hands-on/straight-to-the-point book.

ps: Benjamin, if you read this, imho you now owe me money lol :-)